# Oracle date manipulation

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have this line in code:

```
SELECT (SYSDATE - MAX (STARTED)) * 3600 * 24
```

Started date is : 7.6.2018 14:39:51

What means *3600*24 ???

Thanks

Comment: It shows why comments are needed, even for code that the original developer may think is obvious.  Write for the maintainer that will work on it after you!  :-)  "Clever" code is no good if it takes someone else an hour to figure it out.  It becomes more expensive to maintain. This question is great if only to highlight this problem that I see all the time.  Imagine the time saved if only 5 seconds were spent writing a comment.

Comment: I am with you @Gary - and I also think it unfair that this question has been down-voted.  If the code was *24 * 60 * 60 then there is some clue as to what's going on.  3600 looks a little random at first glance. If you've not done the days to seconds manipulation in the past this is a fair question

Comment: @ChristianPalmer When I learned C back in the day our rule was never use "magic" numbers known only to the original developer  (like the 3600-what does that mean?). Instead define a constant with a meaningful name and use that.  That methodology would have helped here.  Imagine `SELECT (SYSDATE - MAX (STARTED)) * MINS_IN_HR * SECS_IN_MIN * HRS_IN_DAY`.  Much clearer.  Even better combine all that into a master formula for seconds called DIFF_SECONDS.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between dates is given as number of days.

Number of days *24*60*60 gives the number of seconds.

For example:

```
select diff days,
       diff*24 hours,
       diff*24*60 minutes,
       diff*24*60*60 seconds
from ( select date '2018-06-07' - date '2018-06-06' diff from dual)
```

gives

```
      DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         24       1440      86400
```

And this

```
select diff days,
       diff*24 hours,
       diff*24*60 minutes,
       diff*24*60*60 seconds
from ( select to_date('2018-06-07 15:30:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
            - to_date('2018-06-07 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') diff from dual)
```

gives

```
      DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
.063020833     1.5125      90.75       5445
```

Comment: So in my case this  will  return = sysdate - started  multiply with 86400 seconds which is 1 day .

Comment: @civesuas_sine : it will return the difference between the two date fields  (remember an Oracle date holds both date and time) expressed in seconds

Comment: I need to set that difference  multiply with 5 minutes ?
Is that SELECT (SYSDATE - MAX (STARTED)) * 300 ?

Comment: I know that question isnt on the place but I found part of code where i had to change the problem i posted. Here is the code, maybe you guys will get it :

Comment: SELECT (SYSDATE - MAX (STARTED)) * 3600 * 24 
        INTO   p_last_move   FROM ( SELECT STARTED FROM   bus_session  WHERE   party_id = i_player_id and session_type = 'SESSION' and started > (select started from bus_session where session_id = pom_session_id) 
            UNION ALL  select started from bus_session where session_id = pom_session_id
            );     
         IF NVL (p_last_move, 61) > 60   THEN
            player.close_session(i_player_id, i_session_id);
            RETURN NVL (-p_last_move, -61);
         ELSE
                  RETURN pom_credits;
         END IF;